How to make a GET request for fetching specific data inside of Fetch API?
I am new to React and I am trying to get specific search results based on a city name. I have a variable which is entirely dependent on user's input(city name) and I would like to use this variable as a parameter in my URL. I am sure my syntax is wrong and I tried googling, but I cannot understand anything. Can someone please explain how Fetch API works?, and how can I make a GET request with parameters?. Here's my code-
const City1 = useSelector((state) => state.City); // using Redux

const myrequest = fetch('http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/xxxx/:?{$City1}', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((userData) => {
    // Process the retrieved user data
    console.log('User Data:', userData);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });

my error-

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
xxxx.js:66 Error: Error: Network response was not ok

My Server code-
router.get('/:city_name', (req, res, next) => {
  const city_name_code = req.params.city_name;
  schema
    .find({ City: city_name_code })
    .exec()
    .then((doc) => {
      console.log(doc);
      res.status(200).json(doc);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: err }); //  return;
    });
});


Access-Control-Allow-* are response headers, they do not ever belong in your request

Does this answer your question? How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?

Looks like you are using wrong the template string. In your line
 fetch('http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/xxxx/:?{$City1}'

should be with the back ticks `` and the $ outside the curly brackets {}
 fetch(`http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/xxxx/${City1}`

Back ticks tells Javascript that should be a variable to replace, also, the order of ${} is relevant.
On the other hand, the url is right? the ":?"  is needed?

Thanks for the suggestion, it turns out I forgot to include the PORT number in the URL. Without the PORT number, GET methods with parameters do not work. But it works fine for normal GET methods which printout simple messages. I don't understand why this is happening.
